# Implementation using linear congruential equation in java

Tags: java, math, random

I see an LCG implementation in Java under Random class as shown below:

```
/*
 * This is a linear congruential pseudorandom number generator, as
 * defined by D. H. Lehmer and described by Donald E. Knuth in
 * <i>The Art of Computer Programming,</i> Volume 3:
 * <i>Seminumerical Algorithms</i>, section 3.2.1.
 *
 * @param  bits random bits
 * @return the next pseudorandom value from this random number
 *         generator's sequence
 * @since  1.1
 */

protected int next(int bits) {
    long oldseed, nextseed;
    AtomicLong seed = this.seed;
    do {
        oldseed = seed.get();
        nextseed = (oldseed * multiplier + addend) & mask;
    } while (!seed.compareAndSet(oldseed, nextseed));
    return (int)(nextseed >>> (48 - bits));
}
```

But below link tells that LCG should be of the form, x2=(ax1+b)modM

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89185/what-does-linear-congruential-mean

But above code does not look in similar form. Instead it uses & in place of modulo operation as per below line

nextseed = (oldseed * multiplier + addend) & mask;

Can somebody help me understand this approach of using & instead of modulo operation?

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise-ANDing with a mask which is of the form `2^n - 1` is the same as computing the number modulo `2^n`: Any 1's higher up in the number are multiples of `2^n` and so can be safely discarded. Note, however, that some multiplier/addend combinations work *very poorly* if you make the modulus a power of two (rather than a power of two minus one). That code is fine, but make sure it's appropriate for your constants.

Answer (score 1):

This can be used if `mask + 1` is a power of 2.

For instance, if you want to do modulo 4, you can write `x & 3` instead of `x % 4` to obtain the same result.

Note however that this requires that `x` be a *positive* number.